# Find the match or matches with most same values in the same columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I want to find, based on the criteria of a match in my table, which match or matches have the most same criteria in the same columns with priority.

[image]

Could u help me?

I tried with countifs but no result. and i want for a big data thats an example.

Comment: Could you post one or more samples?

Comment: i want to post a screenshot but i cant cause im new user, do u know other way?

Comment: post a link to the picture stored on imgur.com

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LiJwPV5 thats the correct because i want for the exactly sme columns

thanks a lot

Comment: 3 also has 3 in your picture

Comment: yes but i want the groups not uniques

Comment: I still do not understand why 3 is in a group with 4.  And why 2 was left off.

Comment: yes u have right, 2 is in group with 5,6,7,8, & 9 with 2 exactly columns. My mistake in pic

Comment: Would you provide the input sample and the expected output in Table Markdown format, you can use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#). You can copy from your excel, then generate it and copy back to the question. Similarly the logic for the expected output or better the expected output as part of the sample. We don't even know in what format you want the output. If there is any error in your sample data, the expectation is that you update the question properly. There is no need to upload screenshot for a sample data like you have, use table markdown

Comment: hi thanks, i try to use this tool. I m really sorry because my english no so good and i m a new one here. I dont want some specific format from my output, only the right results. Maybe using filter function to show me the rows with same criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean, even though your shared picture shows a different result:

```
=LET(fullrange,  A2:E11,
     number,     TAKE(fullrange,,1),
     data,       DROP(fullrange,,1),
     sumbyrow,   BYROW(data,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x))),
MAP(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),,COLUMNS(data),-1),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(number,sumbyrow=x,"")))))
```

This takes the range `fullrange` and splits the first column `numbers` and the remaining columns `data`

`sumbyrow` sums the matches of the data row by row and creates an array of these.

Then `MAP` performs a `TEXTJOIN` for each `number` where `sumbyrow` equals the sequence of the number of columns of `data` to 1, row by row).

[image]

Comment: You really feel me, thanks a lot bro. It's perfect. Do you know if it possible to add if i want a specific column to be stadard 1 for example column B2?

Comment: B2 is a cell. B:B would be the column (or just B). But I don't understand what you're asking. Do you mean to only include rows where the Criteria1 column equals 1?
Also, if this answered your question, please accept it by clicking the green `V` or by upvoting.

Comment: yes i mean if B column is 1 not 0 no the cell B2. For example IF(B:B=1; mpla mpla with your formula. sorry for my example is ridicoulus i know but i cant handle my english good.

Comment: `=LET(fullrange,A2:E11,filtered,FILTER(fullrange,CHOOSECOLS(fullrange,2)),number,TAKE(filtered,,1),data,DROP(filtered,,1),sumbyrow,BYROW(data,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x))),MAP(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),,COLUMNS(data),-1),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(number,sumbyrow=x,"")))))` is what I think you mean